# UWP Xamarin.Forms 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

My UWP app crashes on *Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assemblies)* with
**Exception thrown:

> 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in
>   System.Private.Reflection.Core.dllFileNotFound_AssemblyNotFound,
>   clrcompression**

The app don't crash if I uncheck *'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'* from Exception settings, but it's not the best solution because if I uncheck this exception I have another problem with Storage API(I can't use the StorageFolder to get files because the execution doesn't return and no exception is thrown).
I don't know if this problem can be releated with the first exception, but
can anyone fix this problem?

Comment: There are many reasons  cause this issue. Could you share more code?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Anyway the problem was async/await method when I use Storage API, and for 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' I had to update Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `async/await` method when I use `Storage API`, and for **`System.IO.FileNotFoundException`** I had to update **Visual Studio.**